# How do I add multiple where conditions in query dynamically using query builder

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have array of parameters and they are coming dynamically I want to make query based on parameters.

**For Example**

```
   $arr Array of parameters
(
  [shareName] => First Item
  [sharePrice] => 100
)
```

**The Query have to add where clause dynamically**

```
       foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        $data = DB::table('itemstable')->where($k, $arr[$k])->where($k, $arr[$k])->get();      
    }
```

how do I know and add two where conditions ?

Comment: you mean "how to use 2 where clause and store it in array?"

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->where([
    ['column_1', '=', 'value_1'],
    ['column_2', '<>', 'value_2'],
    [COLUMN, OPERATOR, VALUE],
    ...
])
```

Comment: Welcome new Stack Overflow-er.  Making a great answer takes time and some experience.  You might find this link helpful in creating fully fledged answers: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: A code-only answer is a low-quality answer. Add some explanation as to why you think this code-snippet would work.